# How do I prevent publishing all the prerequisites every time I publish with ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I have a WinForms ClickOnce application with a lot of prerequisites. I would like to avoid having to publish all of them every time I publish the application.

Is there any way to publish the prerequisites on their own somewhere on my server (they do not change often) and tell the ClickOnce application to look for them at a certain location?

**Update 1**

I am not publishing to a sared folder. I'm publishing to an FTP address.

Comment: If you setup ClickOnce to download prerequisites from the same locationas your application, then when publishin, it doesn't replace prerequisites while why exists on publishing folder location.

Comment: @RezaAghaei that's not true. This is exactly how my project is setup and it publishes all the requisites every time I run a publish

Comment: What I said is completely true and tested using a shared folder on network.